# Pandas groupby custom function to each series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I am having a hard time to apply a custom function to each set of `groupby` column in Pandas

My custom function takes series of numbers and takes the difference of consecutive pairs and returns the mean of all the differences. Below is the code:

```
def mean_gap(a):
    b = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        b.append((a[i+1]-a[i]))
    return np.mean(b)
```

So if `a = [1,3,7]`, `mean_gap(a)` will give me `((3-1)+(7-3))/2) = 3.0`

```
 Dataframe:
   one two
    a  1
    a  3
    a  7
    b  8
    b  9
```

Desired result:

```
     Dataframe:
       one two
        a  3
        b  1
```

`df.groupby(['one'])['two'].???`

I am new to pandas. I read that `groupby` takes values each row at a time, not full series. So I am not able to use lambda after `groupby`.

Comment: it is irrelevant to the question, but is not this function the same as subtracting the first element from the last and dividing by n-1?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With a custom function, you can do:

```
df.groupby('one')['two'].agg(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
one
a    3
b    1
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

and reset the index:

```
df.groupby('one')['two'].agg(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).reset_index(name='two')


    one  two
0   a    3
1   b    1
```

An alternative would be:

```
df.groupby('one')['two'].diff().groupby(df['one']).mean()
one
a    3.0
b    1.0
Name: two, dtype: float64
```

Your approach would have also worked with the following:

```
def mean_gap(a):
    b = []
    a = np.asarray(a)
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        b.append((a[i+1]-a[i]))
    return np.mean(b) 

df.groupby('one')['two'].agg(mean_gap)
one
a    3
b    1
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

`a = np.asarray(a)` is necessary because otherwise you would get KeyErrors in `b.append((a[i+1]-a[i]))`.

Comment: Thanks ayhan! quick question: if I execute only this part "df.groupby('one')['two'].diff()", it doesn't show column 'one'. The output shows only index and values. Why is that? I know it doesn't make sense to show 'one' because the difference is shown for each pair. Is it the property of diff() function not to show 'one' :)

Comment: The methods like `diff`, `cumsum` do not return aggregated results when they are called on groupby objects. For example if you execute `groupby.sum`  in your example, the result will only have rows a and b but for `diff`  and `cumsum`  the result will have 5 rows - same as the original DataFrame. Since there are no aggregation, we generally use them to assign back to the original DataFrame. That's probably why the grouping column does not show up in the returning object.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thanks a lot :)